# Should I let users tag everything in a photos website or just photos?

Tags: website-design, image, tags

I am building a photo hosting/sharing website. I have a feature where users can tag their photos to be able to find and categorize them.

In this website there are albums, slide shows and stories (blog posts that contain photos from the website).

- Should I let the user tag his albums, slide shows and stories, or is it enough to tag photos?
- What will the page the user sees after clicking a tag look like?

Comment: I think you should be more specific, this is not just a UX question, but a site-wide functionality matter. Very subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tag everything that the user is going to want to categorise for later searching. That probably means everything in your case.

You could start with photos and expand it to other items later if you're short of development time.

What the user sees when they select the tag is up to you and your designer. Obviously if you are only tagging photos then it becomes easier as you are only displaying a single type of object, but you should be able to arrange it so that you can show photos, links to stories etc on the same page. Exactly how you do it will depend on your framework.

You could lay it out in sections that can be collapsed and expanded:

> + Photos
>    First few photos arranged in a grid
>
> + Stories
>    Links to the first few stories

and so on